# Free Maven Repository with p2 support for Eclipse Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho, p2, sonatype

I'm trying to find a free-to-use app that can serve as a maven repository with support for eclipse p2 that will allow me to deploy target platforms from a eclipse tycho maven build and I'm conflicted on Sonatype Repository Manager because it seems that p2 support was free in 2x with additional plugins but in 3x it is a pro only feature with a 10 user minimum license. Does anyone know of any other projects that can give me a truly free maven repository with p2 out of the box? -  Thanks in advance.

Comment: We did not find any. Even with Nexus 2.x we did not manage to host a p2 repository. I think it supported only proxying p2, not hosting. We ended up creating a private p2 repository on an internal site which we added as an external repository to Nexus.

Comment: Thanks for saving me the headache of trying Nexus 2.X!